# trouble getting change a property of an outlet in a any new method

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, outlet

I'm having trouble getting change a property of an 
Outlet in a new method, for example:

```
public partial class ViewApresentacao : UIViewController
{
    ...
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        //my ImageView 
        imgModelo.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("Image/car.png");
    }

    //new method
    public void Test(string caminho)
    {
        imgModelo.Image = UIImage.FromBundle (caminho);
    }
    ....
}
```

At `viewDidLoad` functions normally, but the second 
method `Test` did not, wanted to use it 
to update when a selected row in a table, it's all 
ok, but when I call the method `Test`, the error 
"object reference not set to an instance of an object" 
appears well in line of the Outlet.

Comment: This will happen if `Test()` is called before `ViewDidLoad()`.  To fix it, check `IsViewLoaded` within `Test()`, and save your variable in a member variable to be used when it actually loads.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan.Peppers. I will do a test, I'm hitting the head with it some time! Thanks..

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers, in my case the viewDidLoad () is already loaded, because the table is also as an outlet in a corner of my view. Captured from the click event in the cell, but when it calls the method Test () I get an error in the line of Outlet! I do not know what to do!

Sorry if I was not very clear, I'm from Brazil and I'm
using help google translate!

Comment: So if you put a break point in `ViewDidLoad()` it happens before your `Test()` method?  You weren't very convincing in saying your view was already loaded (language barrier).

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers first of all, thanks for the help! I have tested and it really passing through the break point I have put in my ViewDidLoad (), so if I simulate the same error in a simple program with only one screen, can I send you to have a look?

Comment: I am developing a catalog system  for the company I work. Will I need a gallery and in monotouch this was the easiest way I found to do. I simulate the same error in a very simple program for send you to have a look, really i need help with this, seems to be something simple but i can not find examples and places to see a solution. Would be grateful for any help!!

Comment: Actually I think that whatever UIImage.FromBundle (caminho) returns is NULL and not your outlet. Change Test() to:
var image = UIImage.FromBundle (caminho); 
imgModelo.Image = image;
And see in which line the crash is. I bet it is in "var image...", meaning you don't pass the correct value in "caminho".

Comment: hi @Krumelur,
I made the changes you said but it's the same error on the line imgModelo.Image = image; I have simple a example with the error, can I pass you to have a look? I really need to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Please check if the image that is returned by UIImage.FromBundle(caminho) is NULL.

Comment: @Krumelur, enters if yes, but the do a Console.WriteLine(caminho), it shows the message with the right path. What i make?

Comment: I'm not interested in your "caminho" but in the value of the UIImage. if you have "var image = UIImage.FromBundle(cmanhio)", what is the value of "image" after executing this line? Is it NULL?

Comment: @Krumelur Yes, doing: var image = UIImage.FromBundle(pathImage);
if(image == null){Console.WriteLine("Test");}, is shown the message" Test ".

Sorry I'm starting in monotouch!

Comment: I'm sorry if I should, but I sent a simple program with the error for your website http://www.wildsau.net/, contacts tab. I depending on a lot of that in my work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I was in my main class with different instances, with the help Xamarin team, managed to solve my problem.